# Connecting table with multiple foreign keys in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

I have a database table with the following information :

```
owner.primaryitowner, 
owner.secondaryitowner, 
owner.primarybusinessowner, 
owner.secondarybusinessowner
```

The issue, is the owners are only stored as emails. There is another table I normally inner join users on `users.username = owner.primaryitowner` to get `users.displayname` so the data reads correctly. The issue is I need to do this for all 4 columns, and when I can only figure out how to connect 1 column in a query. Thanks for the help

P.S. I cannot change the database I am only a report writer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want all the display name for all owners, try something like this:

```
select u.displayname
from users u
inner join owners o on
    o.primaryitowner = u.username
    or o.secondaryitowner = u.username
    or o.primarybusinessowner = u.username
    or o.secondarybusinessowner = u.username
```